# Getting the dijit for a typeAhead in XPages

Tags: xpages

I want to be able to add an onBlur/onkeypress/onChange events to all TypeAhead fields on the form rather than have a developer select every one in the Designer client. The only thing I cannot get a handle on is the onChange event.

When the user selects something in the TypeAhead the onChange event is triggered when adding the code directly to the event in the Domino Designer - so I should be able to replicate that capability with code.

If my typeAhead field is called inputText2 I thought I would be able to do the following

```
        var widget = dojo.byId("#{id:inputText2}")
        dojo.connect(widget, 'onChange', function (){
            alert('1')
        });
```

However this doesn't appear to work...

I tried lowercase onchange

```
        var widget = dojo.byId("#{id:inputText2}")
        dojo.connect(widget, 'onchange', function (){
            alert('1')
        });
```

no luck there either

I tried

```
    var widget = dijit.byId("#{id:inputText2}");
```

but that failed to event select the element entirely

So what do I need to do to trigger the onchange event when selecting an option in the typeAhead?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.....not ideal but it worked for the moment - not generic though, but a start

Copying the way XPages does it....add this to the page

```
             function view__id1__id2__id31__id50_clientSide_onchange(thisEvent) {
                alert('me')
            }
```

and then

```
        dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

                XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
                    XSP.attachEvent("X1","view:_id1:_id2:_id31:inputText2", "onchange", view__id1__id2__id31__id50_clientSide_onchange, false, 2);
                });                     
             });

        });
```

X1 must be unique but everything else can be calculated

Thanks to Serdar Basegmez