# How do I attach an onchange event to a dojo List Text Box in Xpages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Using 8.5.3, I have an Xpage with a value picker that populates a dojo list text box. This works fine. However, I need to populate some other fields based on the selection from the value picker. If I go to the events panel for the ListTextBox in domino designer to add events it shows errors, but from the all properties panel of the ListTextBox there are events listed. These events are client-side events which while not ideal, I can work around. However even a simple alert box does not work from these events.

Here is my sample code:

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="dLinkedGroupsIDsTX"
    multipleSeparator="," intermediateChanges="true" displayLabel="true"
    value="#{document1.dLinkedGroupsTX}" onChange="alert('change');">
</xe:djextListTextBox>
<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1" for="dLinkedGroupsIDsTX"
    dialogTitle="Linked Groups" pickerIcon="add.png" listWidth="700px">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker valueListSeparator=","
            labelSeparator="~">
            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn("","vwGroupLU",4)}]]></xe:this.valueList>
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
It seems from further testing that all the other events seem to fire. onFocus, onClick, etc.. But that doesn't really help me :-( Perhaps there is another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to connect your javascript function to the event after page load (As in Marky's question - [Getting the dijit for a typeAhead in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892326/getting-the-dijit-for-a-typeahead-in-xpages))

Put the following code on your onClientLoad client-side javascript of the XPage or CC:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
  XSP.attachEvent("X1","#{id:dLinkedGroupsIDsTX}", "onchange",
                    function() { alert("changed");}, false, 2);
});
```

X1 must be any unique identifier. Also, remove the onchange attribute from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried implementing your solution (and also the one from Markys question), but it doesn't seem to do anything. Same results -- no firing of the event.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up doing a quick response. I have tested above code now, it's working. XSP.addOnLoad and dojo.addOnLoad works different I guess.

Comment: It does work indeed!! Funny, I just made a solution where I put the value from the valuePicker into a hidden inputText field, then did a partial refresh to the listTextBox based on the hidden field value and then for the onclick event of the listTextBox (which DOES work on its own) I updated the hidden inputText.. A cheesy solution.. but it did work.  I like your solution better. Thanks again!

Comment: In fact, we are adding this event to a secret editbox inside the widget :)